# VS Code quick fix always give "no code actions available"

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code with Go, the quick fix always give "no code actions available".
No matter what's the error or warning, no fix is given.

[image]

Is this my config/environment problem or is it a vscode bug/expected?
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there's meant to be quick fixes available for the errors you tested with the language extension you're using? (what language is this?)

Comment: The language is Go, I expect it add a line package xxx in the beginning of the file. Maybe this is too demanding for this extension, but I never see it can fix something. Or can you tell which specific case it can fix, I will check.

Comment: This suggests that the Go extension only has quick fixes for missing imports: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1484#issuecomment-471829410

Comment: I have a similar issue. Shouldn't 'Quick Fix' be able to handle 'blank line contains whitespace' ?

Comment: This ticket suggests it is a widespread problem: [https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71579](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71579). It is also affecting me for Python code, I always get "No code actions available" no matter what the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, any of the proposed solutions worked, however, even though no quick fixes were available, the code action (the icon of a lightbulb) showed the expected quick fix (in my case, an Interface implementation action.

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem when using the mouse to select a quick fix.
Instead of using the mouse use hot key, it works on win10:

1. Place the cursor on the error.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
3. Use the keyboard to select your fix.

Comment: I have the same problem with Python, but the hot key: 'ctrl+.' doesn't fix it. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: fwiw this is removed by `"key": "cmd+[Period]", "command": "-editor.action.quickFix"` in my macos `keybindings.json` (note my minus to remove and substitute /cmd/ctrl/ for /macos/windows/)

Comment: I had the same problem with C# 6.0.3. The `Ctrl` + `.` worked for me. But it would be great to enable it with the mouse too.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem but with C# project and the Omnisharp extension (C# v1.24.0).

VsCode didn't resolve the namespaces, but instead showed the "No code actions available". After some time I stumbled across this GitHub issue https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5029.

After changing the Omnisharp settings via extension settings menu and setting the value

```
"omnisharp.path": "latest",
```

I restarted my Omnisharp extension and it finally started giving me proper quick fixes.

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have restarted the VS Code and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was that **Omnisharp: Use Modern Net** was set to false. It **needs to be** set to **true**.

I set it to false in the past to be compatible with an older version of Unity.
Now that I am using a newer version of Unity, I installed the **Visual Studio Code Editor** package in Unity and set the above option to true. That solved the issue after restarting Omnisharp.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this was due to duplicate line number in my js file. removing the duplicate line numbers worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my Python project I solved it by switching to the right python interpreter (I'm using a different virtual environment for every project.

I clicked on the python button (bottom of VS Code UI) and set the proper path within my `/path/to/my/project/venv/bin/python`:

[image]

Now when I'm using the shortcuts I'm able to `Add import <some_import>`, for example:

[image]

My VS Code version: 1.52.1

Answer (score 0):

Please run visual studio code as Administrator.
For more information check your Output Console. It happen because one of running programs block your omnisharp and it didn't work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer looks promising. Probably if we take a deeper look to the OmniSharp initialization we can find out if there's any fix available there. Here's a code example I've got from my system: https://gist.github.com/carloswm85/8d570b1fbcba3dab6bc57a88d8b17f8b I'm not able to see any problem there, but maybe someone more knowledgeable can see something.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and by clicking on the extension panel I see the text shown in front of Omnisharp  C# that says reload and this issue has been fixed by clicking on this text, maybe you have more than an extension for the language you code with , if it's doesn't work uninstall one of them and you see this work

Answer (score -6):

Make sure you dont have a badly formatted or empty .sln file.

Comment: @devdanke this is a "VS Code" question not Visual Studio.