# Vscode Omnisharp Always No Quick Fix

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

The VSCode "quick fix" has never been available for me in C#.

Even the most basic quick fix, like importing namespaces for class, auto-implement missing methods from interface, are not available.

I am not sure what went wrong (or maybe this is normal in VSCode? I came from VS Studio C# and these options are available there. Maybe I am just assuming too much).

Here is a very simple illustration of what I meant (Sorry for the Chinese error message - I am not sure how to change Omnisharp locale. It is the standard Compiler complaint saying that you are not implementing one of the interface method):

[image: No quick fix]

Environment:

- Microsoft C# Plugin (ms-dotnettools.csharp): v1.24.4
- VSCODE: v1.66.2 (user setup)
- OS: Windows 10

I tried:

- Using "Ctrl+." instead (as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71579#issuecomment-513199671))
- Adding `"omnisharp.path": "latest" to Omnisharp extension settings (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199959/15828370))
- reinstalling omnisharp
- reinstalling VsCode

So far none worked.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: try to give a look at this question and its answers, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55413215/1974416

Answer (score 1):

I can see that if I press
cmd + . (control .)
then it shows all available quick fix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As already mentioned in my question, that does not work for me. Are you sure you are writing in C#?

Comment: It works for me. I don't know why it doesn't show the Quick Fix button, but pressing Control + . gives me the quick fix